# Geoserver Openlayers 3 getGetFeatureInfoUrl for several points

Tags: raster, geoserver, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I'm using Openlayers 3 with geoserver for showing roads and temperature information from a NetCDF.
When I select a road, I would like to get the temperature information for each coordinate of the road.

Using **getGetFeatureInfoUrl** it's possible to get the information of one point, but if I tried to get it from many points using a loop, it takes much time.

Which is the correct way to do this? Is there a way to send linestring coordinates as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such a thing in standard OGC protocols.

GeoServer has an extension for multidimensional data called "[ncWMS extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/ncwms/index.html)" that adds some extra, but not the particular one you're looking for, which would be called "GetTransect".

Options:

- Implement, or sponsor, GetTransect in GeoServer "ncWMS extensions"
- Implement a WPS process doing the same
- Use ncWMS (the server that inspired the above extensions)